# iOS Core Data Crashes after Logout

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When i'm trying to logout, clearing my all data in core data

```
public func deleteCoreData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if let psc = context.persistentStoreCoordinator {
        if let store = psc.persistentStores.last {
            let storeUrl = psc.url(for: store)
            context.perform({
                self.context.reset()
                do {
                    try psc.remove(store)
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: storeUrl)
                    try psc.destroyPersistentStore(at: storeUrl,
                                                   ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                                   options: nil)
                    try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                               configurationName: nil,
                                               at: storeUrl,
                                               options: nil)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                completion(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But 1/10 times it crashes

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreData                             0x00000001870b3e44 _nameForEntityDescription + 8
1   CoreData                             0x00000001870b3e20 -[NSSQLCore entityForFetchRequest:] + 40
2   CoreData                             0x00000001872b9af0 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext initWithRequest:context:sqlCore:] + 584
3   CoreData                             0x000000018721b45c -[NSSQLObjectFaultRequestContext createFetchRequestContext] + 120
4   CoreData                             0x00000001872bdeb0 _executeObjectFaultRequest + 80
5   CoreData                             0x00000001872be644 _executeNewRowValuesForObjectFaultRequest + 184
6   CoreData                             0x000000018721b498 -[NSSQLObjectFaultRequestContext executeRequestCore:] + 16
7   CoreData                             0x0000000187121000 -[NSSQLStoreRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 244
8   CoreData                             0x00000001871a3ba4 __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 80
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001840c0a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001840c95bc _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 52
11  CoreData                             0x00000001871a3aa0 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 252
12  CoreData                             0x00000001872940cc -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 260
13  CoreData                             0x00000001871d58f8 -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 232
14  CoreData                             0x00000001870c3ab0 -[NSSQLCore newValuesForObjectWithID:withContext:error:] + 316
15  CoreData                             0x00000001870e1ef4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _conflictsWithRowCacheForObject:withContext:andStore:] + 144
16  CoreData                             0x00000001870e1698 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _checkRequestForStore:withContext:originalRequest:andOptimisticLocking:] + 1560
17  CoreData                             0x00000001871b0d34 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 1512
18  CoreData                             0x00000001871a9758 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 264
19  CoreData                             0x00000001870b3130 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 412
20  CoreData                             0x00000001870d418c -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1260
```

I'm unable to figure out the issues from these terrible logs.

Comment: Looks like somewhere else in your App is still working with Core Data when you try deleting it.  This log shows the crash has come from a save operation on the context.  So it is not in the code you pasted, but somewhere else.

Comment: Yes those logs show that the crash was caused by a save operation, you read from bottom up.  In the code you pasted you are not doing a save.  Therefore the issue is that you are doing a save somewhere else at the same time as you are deleting the PSC.

Comment: Something is : 0x00000001870d418c -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]

Comment: The crash is occurring because somewhere in your App there is a save operation happening after (or at the same time) as you have deleted the Core Data PSC.